# Wrong marker displaying on heatmap(ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-maps

I have a repository method that gets data from a `table` and returns a `list`.

Here is code of this repository method:

```
public List<HeatMapViewModel> GetStops()
    {
        using (TraxgoDB ctx = new TraxgoDB())
        {
            List<HeatMapViewModel> items = new List<HeatMapViewModel>();

            var firstitem = ctx.Logging.Where(x => x.Datatype == Datatype.Start).AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();

            var midnight = new DateTime(firstitem.CurrentDateTime.Year, firstitem.CurrentDateTime.Month,
                firstitem.CurrentDateTime.Day, 00, 00, 00);
            TimeSpan difference = (firstitem.CurrentDateTime - midnight);
            var difference_after_midnight = (int)difference.TotalMinutes;

            items.Add(new HeatMapViewModel
            {
                Latitude2 = firstitem.Latitude,
                Longitude2 = firstitem.Longitude,
                FirstStartDifference = difference_after_midnight
            });

            var lastItem = ctx.Logging.Where(x => x.Datatype == Datatype.Stop).AsEnumerable().LastOrDefault();
            var before_midnight = new DateTime(lastItem.CurrentDateTime.Year, lastItem.CurrentDateTime.Month,
                lastItem.CurrentDateTime.Day, 23, 59, 00);
            TimeSpan difference_before = (before_midnight - lastItem.CurrentDateTime);
            var difference_before_midnight = (int)difference_before.TotalMinutes;

            items.Add(new HeatMapViewModel
            {
                Latitude2 = lastItem.Latitude,
                Longitude2 = lastItem.Longitude,
                LastStartDifference = difference_before_midnight
            });

            var allitems = ctx.Logging;
            var filteredQuery = allitems.Where(x => x.Datatype == Datatype.Start || x.Datatype == Datatype.Stop).OrderByDescending(x => x.LogID).ToList();

            for (int i = 1; i < filteredQuery.Count; i++)
            {
                if (filteredQuery[i].Datatype == Datatype.Stop && filteredQuery[i - 1].Datatype == Datatype.Start)
                {
                    TimeSpan differenceTicks = filteredQuery[i - 1].CurrentDateTime - filteredQuery[i].CurrentDateTime;

                    items.Add(new HeatMapViewModel
                    {
                        Latitude2 = filteredQuery[i].Latitude,
                        Longitude2 = filteredQuery[i].Longitude,
                        Difference = (int)differenceTicks.TotalMinutes
                    });
                }
            }
            return items;
        }
    }
```

And thats the controller that returns data from the repository method:

```
public JsonResult Stops()
    {
         var stops = repoEntities.GetStops();
         return Json(stops.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I set a breakpoint in the controller method and see that it gets three elements:

[image: screen]

And in dev console in chrome I see three elements:

[image: Chrome]

But on the map i only see one marker:

[image]

Where is my mistake or what did i miss out?

Answer (score 0):

I found where is problem

In `firstitem` and `lastitem` I return properties `LastStartDifference` and `FirstStartDifference` instead of `Difference`.